# Ignoring Dependencies in Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have a package which has 5 dependencies -- one of which is MVC3. While installing this package, I want to ignore the dependency on MVC3 alone. Is there a way I can do that?

In the Nuget Package Manager Console, there's an option to ignore dependencies when installing packages --

```
Install-Package <package name> -IgnoreDependencies
```

I want to know if there is a way to mention a specific dependency to ignore, rather than ignoring all dependencies.

Comment: Is this a private package? As in, did you create this package yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-install-package) don't name any options like that. You'll have to ignore all dependencies, then install the ones you need separately. I believe you'll also have to ignore all dependencies when calling Update-Package, and update the other dependencies individually, if you ever use that.

If you're the creator of the package, you can [set MVC3 as a development dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#excluding-development-dependencies), but that won't help if someone else controls the package.

Answer (score 8):

If you are creating your own package you an add the following to your nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="MVC3" version="1.6.4" developmentDependency="true"     />
</packages>
```

Note the line beginning `<package`. When creating your own package you can exclude individual packages using `developmentDependency="true"`. This will remove that package as a dependency. The example I have provided is just dummy data. You can read more about this feature [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#excluding-development-dependencies-when-creating-packages)